# How to add custom routes to Symfony 2 before container compilation?

Tags: symfony, routes

Let me explain the case in further details because the title doesn't explain it very well without being too long.

I'm building a mini framework on top of SF2 to use with our legacy system. We developed a mini, simple plugin system, each plugin will have its own routing.xml which may look like this:

```
routes:
  admin_plugins:
    pattern:  /manager/
    defaults: { _controller: plugins\riCore\AdminController::indexAction }
```

We want to obviously add these routes into the routeCollection, but there is 1 tweak: we want to prepend the route pattern and id with the plugin name. We used to loop through the list of plugin and do it manually like this:

```
self::$container->get('router')->getRouteCollection()->add($plugin_lc_name . '_' . $key, new Route($route['pattern'], $route['defaults'], $route['requirements'], $route['options']));
```

However, now that we moved to use SF2 kernel and do a compilation of the container, we began to run into this problem:

```
[21-Oct-2012 08:40:57] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection::__set_state() in plugins\cache\prod\pluginsProdProjectContainer.php on line 791
```

So I figured it could be due to the fact that we tried to getRouteCollection() the too soon and perhaps there must be a way around?

Comment: http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/01/symfony2-dynamically-add-routes/

Comment: I have tried the link given by you, but ran into this issue: Cannot load resource “.”. 

What I want to do is: I need to dynamically add routes via php (instead of config file) so that I can prepend prefixes manually (maybe there is a way to do it with the config file as well?). I don't know if I can do this AFTER the container has been compiled or not.

Comment: Okie more comments: it's possible to do so $container->get('router')->getRouteCollection()->add() does work. I'm just thinking to see if it would be better to automatically prefix the routes first, cache to routing config files. I'm just wondering if it does help (does symfony caches routes?)

Comment: This might be a solution for you http://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2016/02/25/modular-routing-in-symfony

Comment: @TomášVotruba This is similar to what I already have in my answer, and it is working well for me. However, in my case I need to add routes via database, so when I add new routes I have to flush out the cache folder for routes, which is also fine for now.

Comment: @mr1031011 I see. Where exactly do you add them?
Touching RouteCollection too late might cause some inconsistencies. The reference solution should be fine for database routes as well.

Could you link your whole solution including flushing cache folder for routes? It sounds interesting.

Comment: Sure, I will put the code on gist or somewhere and post here early next week :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my question, yes it seems to work. I just haven't found a way to make SF2 cache those routes yet. Below is part of the code I'm using to add dynamic routes. As you can see I want to add certain prefixes to routes

```
$plugin_lc_name = strtolower($plugin);
                foreach ($plugins_settings[$plugin]['routes'] as $key => $route) {
                    $route = array_merge(array('pattern'      => '',
                                               'defaults'     => array(),
                                               'requirements' => array(),
                                               'options'      => array()), $route);
                    if (strpos($route['pattern'], '/') !== false)
                        $route['pattern'] = $plugin_lc_name . $route['pattern'];
                    else
                        $route['pattern'] = $plugin_lc_name . '_' . $route['pattern'];

                    $container::get('router')->getRouteCollection()->add($plugin_lc_name . '_' . $key, new Route($route['pattern'], $route['defaults'], $route['requirements'], $route['options']));
                }
```

Comment: For those interested, if you run this code in your compiler pass routes will be cached